# Ubuntu Crashing Frequently

Tags: 14.04, server, shutdown, lamp

I am running a Ubuntu-14.04 x64 minimal. It has 64gb RAM, Hexa Core (3.2ghz) and some other stats, that are quite overpowered for my current usage (as i think). The system runs a mysql server and apache2 with php5.
My Website has about 10-20k views a day. But as i mentioned the server is quite overpowered, so i am not getting any performance issues.

The problem is that it sometimes just shuts down. In `kern.log` i couldn't find anything that helps, so i need to know which logs i can check to get more information. Or any other hints what can cause the server to shutdown. It is a **real shutdown, not a restart** btw.

```
hid-generic 0003:0557:2221.0002: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.6/input1, status -110
```

Thats the only message i am getting from kern.log, I know it tells me something about hid, which should actually not be connected to the server, as the server is rented.

**Update**
It shuts down every 3 weeks rightnow. Not every day.

**Update**
Kernal message caused by

from `lsusb -t`

```
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci-pci/2p, 480M
|__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 3, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
```

from `lsusb -v`
found out that first is a mouse, second is a keyboard.

**Update** just rightnow i got this error too

```
perf samples too long (2510 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50000
```

Comment: Can you find if any devices with a similar ID are in `lsusb`, `lshw`, `lsusb` etc? HID devices are mouse keybaords etc so one connected may be causing issues, though usually this should not be serious enough to cause a crash.... if it is shutting down properly [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9819/how-to-find-out-from-the-logs-what-caused-system-shutdown) may help.

Comment: I actually found one, `Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0557:2221 ATEN International Co., Ltd Winbond Hermon` but this is a keyboard..

Comment: ok - to get more info on the thing you can use `lsusb -t` and `lsusb -v`, some info may also be in `lshw`.

Comment: I updated my question for readability

Comment: @Wilf also i do not have a shutdown message. only the server start messages `Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset [...]` and the `hid` messages

Comment: Are you monitoring the temperature?  It could be something simple like a fan that's got a loose connector...

Comment: I rent the server, so i don't monitor it myself, where can i check logs or set some up to monitor?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install lm-sensors` followed by `sudo sensors-detect` will instruct you which modules to load for sensor support. After those are loaded, running `sensors` will tell you the readings of all those.

Comment: And `cron` the `sensors` every minute and add a `date` to the file so you can see the fluctuations over time...

Comment: Hi i will try that one. And post results here.

Comment: Might the server simply be losing power? I get the message about the kernel performance interval on my system without seeing any resulting problem. A keyboard or mouse problem shouldn't crash your system.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately i let the service men check the server, no mouse or keyboard was plugged. Rightnow monitoring temperature, while waiting for the next crash :(

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend turning off acpi to rule out a false sensor or condition based shutdown if you disable acpi, then the only other way would be by script or someone remotely entering a shutdown command.

its better to adjust your grub - you will not have to keep changing it when a new kernel comes along.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

change the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

to read something like

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="noapic"
```

or

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi=off"
```

save then

```
sudo update-grub
```

to finish.

But, as sysadmin, I would tell you that if you are really serious about serving webpages, get a Debian loaded dedicated server. They are so cheap now a days. you can spend $40 bucks a month with 100MBPS line unmetered. **ISPCONFIG** is a free control panel with all the frills you might ever want.

Comment: I just took a look at acpi, if i am not wrong, it is about power saving, but wouldn't that generate some log entries in `kern.log`? As my problem seems to come pretty unexpected by the OS itself

Comment: There is such a thing as ACPI SHUTDOWN, which is why I feel you should rule it out. It's the type of shutdown that triggers when you when you tap the power button. You might have a faulty power button, who knows. Which is why we should eliminate the many possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I have some IT server administration experience, 64 gibs of RAM sounds like where your problem is coming from,that configuration leaves allot of possibility for hardware failure, from what you are describing it sounds like one of your memory sticks gets hot it fails and causing a system shutdown to protect damage, it is summer now, I would try a process of elimination solution here, start off using just x4 memory sticks configuration, you probably have x4 16GB mem sticks, one of them may be faulty, isolate them to see which one is broken, secondly you do know that Ubuntu has Server versions of their OS, why are you running desktop OS minimum with server apps? Install Ubuntu server OS, vervid monkey 64bit server is available, which probably has routines to handle 64gb mem configs, If these two fixes don't change any behavior then you know its not the OS or the Sticks..process of elimination, its not that so it must be that...

Comment: if this is your problem you should be able to get an idea with memtestx86 from the ubuntu grub bootloader (it gets added to grub if it is installed - the packe is called "memtest86+"

Comment: Unfortunately this is something i will not be able to check on, memtest needs input/interrupt at booting, while i can only connect to server via ssh and the manual check is impossible too as i cannot access the server physically.

Comment: @Michael Wakelin thanks for the OS hint, thought the server version is simply skipping desktop apps.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you need to gather more information - if the above mentioned memtestx86+ doesn't reveal a memory problem - some other hint should be discoverable.

we use kibana to gather logfiles onto a central server for further investigation:

https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana

that is posibly a way to find the problem...